# Where was this Cisco photo taken?

Tags: identify-this, photography

The following photograph is from the Cisco TelePresence system. I assume it's not AI-generated, since it has been around for more than 10 years already (AI only became so good fairly recently). It might be heavily photoshopped, but in all likelihood it's a real-world location. Anyone knows what it could be? I suppose it could be California, because that's where Cisco is headquartered, but it doesn't look like a stereotypical Californian landscape.

[image]

Comment: You are aware that there are ski resorts in California, right? California is not just Southern California beaches and palm trees, the climate and geography are extremely varied.

Comment: see also https://stock.adobe.com/images/Dramatic-autumn-sunset-in-the-mountain/70867597 which looks like the same original photo but one has been modified

Comment: And CA gets a lot of its water from the [snowpack](https://cdec.water.ca.gov/snowapp/sweq.action)

Comment: there are ski resorts in Southern California (Big Bear for example), and Los Angeles had quite a bit of snow just this year.

Comment: @jcaron, everyone, oh yes, I know there are ski resorts and mountains in California, incl. the highest peak of the Lower 48. :-) But still, never having been there, I wasn't sure where this scene is.

Comment: The (suspected) original photo actually looks more like Eastern Carpathian mountains of Ukraine and Romania.

Comment: Honestly it looks like low mountains with a bit of frost (possibly snow) and mist about anywhere in the world. I’m not sure there are enough specific features in that photo to find where it is. But my point was that your “stereotypical Californian landscape” is quite reductive.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko I think Midavalo found the original (un-edited) photo on Adobe.  Andrew Mayovskyy is credited for that photo, and if you search for other work by him you'll see a lot of images from the Carpathian mountains.  Still haven't found the actual location of that photo though.

Comment: Yes, I also browsed through other works by the same author. His photos on Shutterstock have more precise geographic location. All of these are labeled "Sokilsky Ridge": https://www.shutterstock.com/g/andrewmayovskyy/sets/11213085

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Given that he is likely to be the photographer, and this image doesn't have  any location data, the best thing to do is to contact him directly via what ever social media account you prefer.

Comment: @PeterM That's a good idea, but I'm mostly fine with the knowledge that this was taken somewhere in the Ukrainian Carpathians. Before I asked, I thought it could be California or anywhere else in the world, so it's a huge improvement :-)